# jquery sometimes does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have been having this problem I have a div with 2 buttons in my HTML

```
<div id="carosel">
 <button  class="navigation" id="nav-left">&lt;</button>
 <button class="navigation" id="nav-right">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

and in my jQuery code, I have this function

```
$("nav-left").hover(function() {
 alert('something');
});
```

when I try from console sometimes it works. I have referenced the javascript file in the header correctly.

Comment: *"when i try from console sometimes it works."* I doubt that, it's trying to select an element with the tag `nav-left`. Your elements are `button`s with the **class** `nav-left`. The selector for that is `.nav-left`, not `nav-left`.

Comment: `$("#nav-left")` you are missing selector

Comment: Your Jquery selector is invalid try $("#nav-left") . # is used to select an item by ID in Jquery.

Comment: shihan  did you checked the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite simple, you forgot a "#" initiative at the beginnging the selector, you should try run the following

```
   $("#nav-left").hover(function() {
 alert('something');
});
```

Comment: Don't answer this type question, its just a typo. and better to close.

Comment: Trying to contribute for once :)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

First, your selector should be #nav-left. jQuery uses css selectors, so you need to use the # to reference an element with an ID of nav-left. (Whereas you would use .nav-left if your element had a class of nav-left rather than an id)

Second, when you move from the console to your own file (or inline script), you will want to wrap your JavaScript in a

```
$(document).on('ready', function (){
 <Your code here> 
})
```

This will ensure that your DOM will have actually renderered before you try to manipulate it with jQuery.